# Ways to design plugin

Tags: php, plugins

I designed two forms of plugin for my CMS but I have problem with one of them. The first one which will be implemented in the templates, it's cool there is no problem with that. But the second one which is for my admin area, I designed it in this way.

First I defined an instruction file which is a text file with this content:

```
REPLACE_INLINE("sample.php","//Echo/*","//Echo*/","echo \"test\"","echo \"new test\"");
```

In my plugin install function I split up these arguments and I go to do them and at last I save the new content. It works fine but I want to know, is it the right way of designing plugins? I think It's not and for that I posted a topic.

By the way my sample.php file which I assume that It's one of my CMS's source files contains this data:

```
<?php
  function showText(){
    //Echo/*
    echo "test";
    //Echo*/
  }
?>
```

And one thing else, If I do this, maybe next time another plugin wants to interact some data with the echo "test"; line And if it wouldn't be like the main template then we're gonna boom ! crash.

The sample.php data after plugin installation:

```
<?php
  function showText(){
    //Echo/*
    echo "new test";
    //Echo*/
  }
?>
```

Comment: this question is hard to answer with the information you have prodived because the design of your CMS is unspecified. I would say as well that your plugin design is not really a design at all, but I can not make any better suggestion. Normally this is done with callbacks so you can extend your existing code dynamically.

Comment: Thanks. It's not kinda designing like MVC or other things It's just a way to solve a problem. I have a problem with extending. If there is a class which generate my post form by function genForm_Post();, so If I wanted to install a plugin to add something in my form, everywhere not just the first or the bottom of my form, so How should I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having to textually replace content, you should either go with an object-oriented architecture where subclasses can overwrite `showText` (and/or call the old implementation) or  use callbacks, like this:

```
$plugin_callbacks = array();
function showText() {
  $text = 'test';
  foreach ($plugin_callbacks as $cb) {
    $text = call_user_func($cb, $text);
  }
  echo $text;
}

$plugin_callbacks[] = function($text) {
  return 'new text';
}
$plugin_callbacks[] = function ($text) {
  return '<b>' . $text . '</b>';
};
```

However, as you can see, this can get messy soon. Therefore, unless there is a very limited number of callbacks, use an **object-oriented design** (which will require you to have an instantiation factory where plugins can register and determine which type the echoObject will be).

Comment: Yep ! that's what I'm saying. How to modify and/or add data. Thanks. But as you said, It can get messy soon but anyway, If you should do something, Then you should do it.

Answer (score 0):

A much more organized way would be to go [Object Oriented](http://php.net/oop). For instance, build an abstract `Plugin` base class and extend that in your plugins.

For your admin area, you can create an `AdminPlugin` with some additional requirements and/or added base functionality. Like a `getText()` function, which would *return* the text (you're admin area should ultimately render it).

You can also include dependency management in your objects, to prevent a crash like you described.

Comment: Yep. I know it, As I said I have two forms of plugins the first one which is public and common is based on hooking like Linux kernel or WordPress. But in admin area you should be able to add some extra data or modify the existing data with plugins. That's my point. My example is just an example It's not the real source in my CMS.

Comment: Ah, fair enough.. Wasn't obvious to me.